# Как в WP очистить медиабиблиотеку?

Tags: php, wordpress

Мне надо полностью удалить все изображения из медиабиблиотеки. Физически с сервера я их уже снес.

Пробую так:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '2056M');
ini_set('max_execution_time', 900);

$params = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 1000,
    'post_type' => 'attachment'
);
$q = new WP_Query( $params );
if( $q->have_posts() ) :
    while( $q->have_posts() ) : $q->the_post();
        wp_delete_post( $q->post->ID, true );
    endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Не работает. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Есть доступ к мускулу?

Comment: @Walfter есть..

Comment: Только через админку или с пом плагинов будет правильно и безопасно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Зайти в тот же phpMyAdmin и выполнить(если у вас всё стандартное, и не было своих внедрений которые могли оставить мусор в базе)

Выполнить следующий запрос:

```
DELETE FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id IN (SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'attachment');
```

Сейчас посмотрел в базе WP и правильно будет удалить и комментарии

```
DELETE FROM wp_commentsmeta WHERE comment_id IN (SELECT comment_ID FROM wp_comments WHERE comment_post_ID IN (SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'attachment'));

DELETE FROM wp_comments WHERE comment_post_ID IN (SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'attachment');
```

И только затем

```
DELETE FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'attachment';
```

Вы должны понимать что они могут быть использованы в постах, и правильней было бы удалить их с помощью подобного [плагина](https://wp-kama.ru/plugin/media-cleaner) так как запросы удалять данные из таблиц которые я предполагаю что хранят инфу о этих записях

**И не забывайте делать бэкапы!!!!**

Comment: Ну и нафик было давать SQL-запросы если знаешь как правильно делать?

Comment: @SeVlad не совсем уверен что автор хочет удалить только те что не использованы в постах

Comment: Чтобы не хотел автор - нельзя лазить в базу такими грязными методами. Да  и вообще нельзя, кроме как сменить пароль или мыло.

Comment: @РашенБеар, к сож, не осознаёшь ничего этого,  раз задаёшь такие вопросы и тем более удалял руками файлы, .Ответ на него - в знании структуры базы, понимании сериализованных данных и АПИ. Да хотя бы посмотреть код wp_delete_attachment м всех связанных функций и крепко задуматься.